# Strapi - get last content changed date

Tags: javascript, gatsby, strapi

I'm building a website and would like to use strapi CMS as the backend. Since my website will be built with Gatsby, I planned of using a cron task on the server to build the website every day, if the content has changed.

Is there a functionality in Strapi that let me retrieve the last content changed date? Or should I create it myself (if it's possible)?

EDIT:

Sadly, I can't use webhooks because I'm forced into a PLESK control panel.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there is a functionality to achieve this in all CMS, they are called webhooks. Some CMS added the functionality (but only under `gatsby development`, like DatoCMS does). Adding a webhook is much more efficient than creating a cron job to build each day, since it may cause unnecessary deploys if there isn't new or edited content and may cause big delays until the content is added to the content is deployed.

According to Strapi's documentation:

> A webhook is a way for an application to notify other applications
> that an event occurred. Using a webhook is a good way to tell third
> party providers to start some processing (CI, build, deployment ...).
>
> The way a webhook works is by delivering information to a receiving
> application through HTTP requests (typically `POST` requests).

You may find this [guide interesting](https://strapi.io/blog/building-a-static-website-using-gatsby-and-strapi#12webhookswithgatsbystrapi). It shows you step by step how to create a webhook in your CD system.

---

> Sadly, I can't use webhooks because I'm forced into a PLESK control
> panel.

In this case, since Plesk does only accept GitHub webhooks, you are forced to choose your cron implementation.

Comment: Hi Ferran, that looks very interesting indeed! Only problem is that I'm forced into a PLESK environment and I'm not entirely sure that it supports custom webhooks that could be used for building (i looked it up, but seems to only support git webhook)...

Comment: Plesk doesn't support external webhooks rather than GitHub indeed. I'm afraid you will have to try the cron job.

Comment: Well, thank you for your answer anyway, it did pointed me to some interesting docs that i can use to create the "get last changed date" functionality myself. I'll wait for other answers for accepting, but i'll +1 yours, since it will be useful to many other users